# pytest-django doesn't load the settings module

Tags: django, pytest

I have my django settings module in `/my_app/settings.py` and have `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` set to `my_app.settings`. Inside the settings I have a print statement, but it doesn't get executed when I run `py.test`. I have pytest-django installed, checked it by doing `import pytest_django`.

I need the `settings` module loaded because it sets some important bits.

Also, the weird thing is that putting `print 'test'` inside a test doesn't print it. Does pytest do some magic whereby it does not actually import the test?

How can I fix my situation?

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` file in your `/myapp` directory?

Comment: Yes of course. I can do `import my_app.settings` in the python shell.

Comment: dou you have pytest.ini or any equivalent ?

Comment: I do, I have it set to [this](https://gist.github.com/rokcarl/70b71e79e96e3d41c732).

Comment: maybe py.test cannot find your settings have you read this http://pytest-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managing_python_path.html#managing-the-python-path ?

Comment: Actually, I have a [ticket](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/204) open.

Comment: What is the error you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Pytest executes the print statements, and remembers what was printed, but only displays it if the test fails.